# What is your Instagram password when you login from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, passwords, instagram

I've created my Instagram account by logging in through Facebook. Now whenever I have to log in from a laptop or a PC they say my password is incorrect (since they don't have a "login with Facebook option"). I tried using my Facebook password but it didn't work. What to do?

Answer (score 4):

When you login account using Facebook it synchronize your account with Facebook by using details from Facebook and didn't ask for password. But when you login account from a separate device or PC, it will ask for the password.

See from the [Instagram Help Center](https://help.instagram.com/409847499070242) how to reset/create a new password:

> If you can't remember your password, you can reset it through your email address or your Facebook account. To reset your password, first tap **Forgot**? next to **Password** on the log in screen.
>
> - To reset through your email address, tap **Username or Email**, enter your username or the email address you used to create your account and tap search. Choose **Send a Password Reset Email**.
> - To reset through Facebook, tap **Reset using Facebook**. You may be asked to log into Facebook. You can then enter a new password for the Instagram account that was most recently [linked](https://help.instagram.com/176235449218188) to your Facebook account.
>
> If you can't access the email you registered with and you didn't link your Instagram account to Facebook, we're not able to give you access to this account.

For above activity I would suggest instead of app, go to [instagram.com](https://instagram.com/) and change password.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the app where you originally signed up and click the option to change your password and then set one there.